# Having trouble with linked list functions

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm having trouble using a member function of a pointer to a video object.
My code is as follows:

vlist.h:

```
 5 #ifndef VLIST_H
 6 #define VLIST_H
 7 
 8 #include<iostream>
 9 using namespace std;
10 
11 #include<string>
12 #include"video.h"
13 
14 class Vlist
15 {
16  public:
17   Vlist();
18  // ~Vlist();
19   void insert(Video *vid);
20  // void insert_alphabetical(Video *vid);
21   void print();
22   // void length();
23   bool lookup(string title);
24   bool remove(string title);
25  private:
26   class Node
27   {
28    public:
29     Node(Video *vid, Node *next)
30     {m_vid = vid; m_next = next;}
31     Video *m_vid;
32     Node *m_next;
33   };
34   Node *m_head;
35 };
36 
37 #endif
```

vlist.cpp:

```
  5 #include<iostream>
  6 using namespace std;
  7 
  8 #include<string>
  9 #include"vlist.h"
 10 #include"video.h"
 11 
 12 Vlist::Vlist()
 13 {
 14  m_head = NULL;
 15 }
 16 
 17 void Vlist::insert(Video *vid)
 18 {
 19  m_head = new Node(vid, m_head);
 20 }
 21 
 22 void Vlist::print()
 23 {
 24  Node *ptr = m_head;
 25  while(ptr != NULL)
 26  {
 27   cout << ptr->m_vid->print();
 28   ptr = ptr->m_next;
 29  }
 30 }
```

video.h:

```
5 #ifndef VIDEO_H 
6 #define VIDEO_H
7 
8 #include<iostream>
9 using namespace std;
10 
11 #include<string>
12 
13 class Video
14 {
15  public:
16   Video(string title, string url, string comment,float length, int rating);
17   ~Video();
18   void print();
19 
20  private:
21   string m_title;
22   string m_url;
23   string m_comment;
24   float m_length;
25   int m_rating;
26 };
27 
28 #endif
```

Video.cpp:

```
 5 #include<iostream>
 6 using namespace std;
 7 
 8 #include<string>
 9 
10 #include "video.h"
11 
12 using namespace std;
13 
14  Video::Video(string title, string url, string comment, float length, int rating)
15  {
16   m_title = title;
17   m_url = url;
18   m_comment = comment;
19   m_rating = rating;
20   m_length = length;
21  }
22 
23  /* Video::~Video()
24  {
25   cout << "object is desructing" << endl;
26  } */
27 
28  void Video::print()
29  {
30   cout << m_title << ", " << m_url << ", " << m_comment << ", " << m_length << ", ";
31   for(int i = 0; i < m_rating; i++)
32  {
33   cout << "*";
34  }
35  cout << endl;
36  }
37
```

main.cpp:

```
 5 #include<iostream>
 6 using namespace std;
 7 
 8 #include<string>
 9 #include"video.h"
10 #include"vlist.h"
11 
12 int main()
13 {
14  int num_vids = 0;
15  Video *vids;
16  Vlist vlist;
17 
18  string title, url, comment; // for title, url, and comment
19  float length; // for the length
20  int rating; // for the rating
21 
22  string choice; // what the user wants to do
23 
24  cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
25  cout << "insert" << endl;
26  cout << "print" << endl;
27  cout << "length" << endl;
28  cout << "lookup" << endl;
29  cout << "remove" << endl;
30 
31  while(getline(cin, choice))
32  {
33   if( (choice == "insert") )
34   {
35    getline(cin, title);
36    getline(cin, url);
37    getline(cin, comment);
38    cin >> length;
39    cin >> rating;
40    cin.ignore();
41 
42    vids = new Video(title, url, comment, length, rating);
43    vlist.insert(vids);
44    num_vids++;
45    // cout << "you would like to insert something" << endl;
46   }
47 
48   else if( (choice == "print") )
49   {
50    // cout << "you would like to print something" << endl;
51    vlist.print();
52   }
53 
54   else if( (choice == "length") )
55   {
56    cout << num_vids << endl;
57   }
58 
59   else if( (choice == "lookup") )
60   {
61    cout << "you would like to look something up!" << endl;
62   }
63 
64   else if( (choice == "remove") )
65   {
66    cout << "you would like to remove something" << endl;
67   }
68 
69   if( (choice != "insert") && (choice != "print") && (choice != "length") && (choice    != "lookup") && (choice != "remove") )
70   {
71    cerr << choice << " is not a legal command, giving up." << endl;
72    return 1;
73   }
74  }
75 
76 
77  return 0;
78 }
```

Basically right now im just trying to use insert and choice. When I input insert, i want to make a new video object and put that into into the m_vid spot in a linked list Node. then i want to call print and do vlist.print() and print all the Videos that i inserted into the linked list. Line 27 of vlist.cpp is not doing out the Video member function print, and im not sure why. i get the error message vlist.cpp:27:29: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << ptr->Vlist::Node::m_vid->Video::print()'. so im just trying to insert videos into the linked list then print them all out. what is going wrong? If you need any extra clarification, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VList::print()` is void, you can't pass to `cout`.

update:

```
cout << ptr->m_vid->print();
```

to:

```
ptr->m_vid->print();
```